Is there any migration mechanism for altering table schema in Ibis?
We are planning to shift from infi.clickhouse to ibis, so I was wondering, does ibis support the migration of old schema to new like infi.clickhouse?
If not, then what could be the solution to this?
Is it good decision to shift to Ibis?
I am thinking of keeping infi.clickhouse for migration and change all the other components to ibis, is it a good approach, or is there any other library that would be better to shift to?

May I know the benefit of the moving?

no internal ibis project migration support AFAIK

@jsc0218, We are currently using infi.clickhouse_orm, the community support of this is not very much as of now, so we have decided to move it to some other library, we are considering sqlalchemy, but shifting to ibis is much easier.
